# Where did all the Mandalorian gear come from?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars, the-mandalorian

In the final episode of *The Mandalorian* season 1, Din Djarin finds the Armorer surrounded by a pile of armor. She claims some of the Mandalorian have escaped off-world, but it is a big pile, and there weren't many to begin with.

Where did this armor come from? Were there this many Mandalorians on the planet who got killed, and this is their leftover armor? Or was it a set of equipment she had previously?

Comment: i'd have to rewatch the episode to be sure, but i think it's implied that the armor is mostly from mandalorians that were killed

Comment: It was all of the equipment that they had. It could be spares, old ones, armor from the dead, and from other sources.

Comment: An alternative idea that I (and the friends I was watching with) came up with was that they had abandoned the Order, hence why the armour wasn't bloodied.